# Installing xSwipe

Tags: linux, fedora

I'm running latest Fedora, and I'm trying to compile xSwipe, but i seem to get an error:

```
Couldn't find synaptics properties. No synaptics driver loaded?
```

i followed the guide here https://github.com/iberianpig/xSwipe
and added the lines to /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/50-synaptics.conf, and still i get an error.

thanks in advance.

Comment: anyone can answer pls?